# atexit in python2 and python3 - different behavior

Tags: python, atexit

I just found out the atexit behaves differently in python3. I had the following code:

```
#!/opt/bb/bin/python2.7
import sys
import atexit

@atexit.register
def exitHandler():
    sys.exit(1)
```

If I ran echo $? after this, I will get 1. So we are moving to python3.7. However, after changing to python3.7, echo $? gives me 0.

Does anyone know why and how to achieve the same behavior in python2.7.

Comment: See https://bugs.python.org/issue27035